# Bash: combine 2 files, arrange into row, and add equals sign all in one step

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two files that list output in the following format:

File1

```
line1
line2
line3
```

File2

```
20%
30%
40%
```

How can I achieve this format below (single row)from the 2 original files and have this in a new file all in one step?

```
line1=20% line2=30% line3=40%
```

Comment: `paste -d= file1 file2`.

Comment: I need this in a single row, not a column.

Comment: Amending @gniourf_gniourf's suggestion: What with `paste -d= file1 file2| tr '\n' ' ' ` then ;-) ? ... if a pipe qualifies as "in one step".

Comment: Perfect! write that up as an answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the fast feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Amending @gniourf_gniourf's suggestion: Given the two files you call:

```
paste -d= file1 file2| tr '\n' ' '
```

which first creates

1. newline separated pairs from file1 and file2 same line entries
2. joined by `=` and then
3. in the pipe tr(anslate) replaces every newline character `\n` with a single space

... if a pipe qualifies as "in one step".

Answer (score 1):

Dilettant's answer is good, just as an alternative with one more pipe

```
cat file1 file2 | pr -2ts= | xargs
```